# How to extend the line of best fit (polyfit) to cross the y-axis at zero in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, plot, regression, linear-regression

In MATLAB, I want to plot scatter data with a regression.

```
a = [2004.4 2005.6 2002.1 2002.1 2004.8 2002.6 2003.5 2001.3 2003.5 2002.6];
b = [0.1006 0.0848 0.0502 0.0502 0.0909 0.0385 0.0732 0.0732 0.0896 0.0772];
scatter(a, b, 6);
hold on
p = polyfit(a,b,1);
f = polyval(p,a);
plot(a,f,'Color',[0.7500    0.7500    0.7500],'linewidth',1.5)
```

However, I want to extend the line (and the x-axis) so that the line goes through `y=0` and crosses the x-axis at its origin wherever that is, so that it looks something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply have to change the input array of points into `polyval`.  You are using only the points defined in `a` and plotting the line of best fit through those points.  As such, define **more** points where you specify the point where `y=0` happens up to the last point in `a`.  Given the fact that the line of best fit is `y = mx + b` where `m` is the slope and `b` is the intercept, the `x` value to generate `y=0` is simply `-b/m`.  Therefore, the beginning point would simply be `-p(2)/p(1)` in MATLAB syntax referring to your code.  The output of `polyfit` is an array of two values (as you specified the order of fit to be 1) where the first is the slope `p(1)` and the last is the intercept `p(2)`.

Therefore, try doing this. I've left your code intact and have placed comments where I have modified:

```
a = [2004.4 2005.6 2002.1 2002.1 2004.8 2002.6 2003.5 2001.3 2003.5 2002.6];
b = [0.1006 0.0848 0.0502 0.0502 0.0909 0.0385 0.0732 0.0732 0.0896 0.0772];
scatter(a, b, 6);
hold on
p = polyfit(a,b,1);
xx = linspace(-p(2)/p(1), max(a)); %// Change
yy = polyval(p, xx); %// Change 
plot(xx,yy,'Color',[0.7500    0.7500    0.7500],'linewidth',1.5) %// Change
xlim([-p(2)/p(1), max(a)]); %// Change
```

[`linspace`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html) generates a linear-spaced array of points from a minimum to a maximum value.  The amount of points by default is 100.  The minimum would be `-b/m` and the maximum would be the largest value seen in `a`.  Once we generate this array, we then use `polyval` and evaluate what the points along the line would be for each value in the array.  I've also modified the call to your `plot` so that I'm using these new points and to make the graph neat, I change the limits of the `x` values shown to span from where the `x` intercept is up to the largest value in `a`.  That's done with [`xlim`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlim.html) where we can specify the smallest and largest `x` values to focus on in the graph.

We get the following graph:

[image]